# Ngrx/effect executed after all actions

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have effect that adds actions iterating an array:

```
@Effect()
changeId$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionTypes.ChangeId),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromReducers.getAliasesNames)),
  switchMap(([action, aliasesNames]: [ChangeId, string[]]) => {
    const actions: Action[] = [];
    aliasesNames.forEach((alias) => {
      actions.push(new AddField(alias));
    });
    return actions;
  })
);
```

Also i have another effect that listens for `AddField` action:

```
 @Effect()
 update$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionTypes.AddField),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromReducers.GetSomeData)),
  switchMap(([action, someData]: [AddField, string[]]) => {
     // make something depend on adding field
  })
 );
```

The problem is that i expect that update$ effect will be called after every `AddField` action. But instead of this `AddField` caleed three times and then `update$` effect called three times too. I feel that my operators are wrong. Could you please give as advice what operator should i use for this purpose?

Comment: Sounds like your are dispatching multiple actions instead of one containing a payload with all the values. Would probably work better with an `AddFields` action having an array as payload.

Comment: Yes, it is one way of solving my problem. But i expect that effect will be executed after action every time. I don't understand why effect is called only after all actions were handled in reducer.

Comment: If the `update$` effect must run before the reducer, then maybe the workflow needs an intermidiate action. `update$` effect must dispatch the action catched by the reducer.

Comment: update$ effect must me called in usual way - after reducer. But as i wrote, problem is that effect wait for some reasons till all `AddField` actions will be handled by reducer.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine an *action queue* and with effects you can put actions to that queue. In one "cycle" the actions are handled in the following way.

1. Execute reducer
2. Execute effects

This order is [guaranteed](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/162). Imagine you trigger the `changeId` action. What happens is that the reducer is executed and looks for that action. Then the effects are executed. This particular effect puts several `addField` actions to the *action queue*. This is what you mean by

> But instead of this AddField caleed three times ...

In the next step the reducer of the `addField` action executed X times, and then the effects are called X times. And this is what refers to

> and then update$ effect called three times too.

As suggested by @ibenjelloun in the comments already, implement an `addFields` action and have an array of items as payload.